# How to filter a column based of another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
X    Y
A1   1
A2   2
A1   2
A3   3
A1   3
A1   4
```

If `Y` column has range 1 to 4,

- I need to run a script where it returns the corresponding X value for Y in range 1 to 4.
- By example, the output should be A1 when Y range is from 1 to 4.
  (or)
- If Y is 2 output should be A2

I have tried using this

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='X', columns='Y', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
```

But got list of columns for 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: What is your desired output? In actual output / text as part of your question, please, not description.

Comment: actual output should be X column

Comment: But dataframe already has X column..Just use `df['X']`. As I said, description is not most helpful here.

Comment: This is very confusing.  Please read [mcve] and [edit] accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Pandas for dataframes. if that's the case you can use [loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to extract part of the dataframe you need. You can try this snippet:

```
df.loc[df['Y'] in range(1,4), 'X']
```

For more info about loc you can access the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label).